# User Logout upon terminating application in android

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to logout the user of my app automatically when the application has been terminated. I dont believe there is anyway to do this as only the activities have an onTerminate() function call. I am coming from an ios background where i an app, i could call a logout() function when the user entered the background. Is there a similar sort of parallel for android?

The reason i am looking for this option is because i have a global helper class that extends Application to store some user credentials and other info. If the application gets terminated by the os, this data is lost from what i have read. So i would like to force the user to log back in again to repopulate this data if it was destroyed.

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: What Naveen is trying to point out is, is that an application can be killed without warning any time it's not on the screen (i.e. after onPause() or onStop(), depending on O/S version.) This means there's simply no way to be assured that you'll be notified when the application is exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Save user credentials to shared preference, Then when press logout button clear data in shared preference and finish the activities and cancel all background services related to your app

Comment: The whole idea was that there is no clear logout "Button". Its just a security option in the app that it logs you out automatically. Given this, do you have any ideas on how to accomplish the above?